# AeRender.exe After Effect

Tags: virtual-reality, after-effects

I would like to automate a render process of video in after Effects using AeRender.exe.
I am using the node.js for run the Aerender.exe but i am getting the error
"unable to read VR path from registry from c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath"

I am using the following code.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var ae = spawn('/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe After Effects CC 2018/Support Files/aerender.exe',[
'-project', 'template.aep',
'-comp', 'final',
'-output', 'movie.mov',
'-OMtemplate', 'h264'
]);

ae.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
// Error occured
console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ae.on('close', function (code) {
// Video has rendered
```

});

Please help on this topic.

Comment: I know nothing about Adobe AE, but does the user that's running your node app have permissions to access that file? `c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath`

Comment: Thanks for provide suggestion but i am new on node js,could you please given a hint about how to given the permission for aerender.exe